# Does For Each reference objects itself or their values?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, combobox

Here is my problem : i'm working with some `ComboBox` in my WPF app, and I want to fill them with `ComboBoxItemPlus`, which are basicly `ComboBoxItem` with a few more properties in order to link them with data more easily. My problem is that I want to fill these `ComboBox` automaticly. For this, I declare a list of `ComboBoxItemPlus`, instanciate them one by one, and then attribute them a value like this : (in this case, I could do it one by one because there are only seven, but I will have to do this with much more elements after)

```
 Private Sub FillCBB_Jour()
        Dim item(7) As ComboBoxItemPlus

        For Each it As ComboBoxItemPlus In item
            it = New ComboBoxItemPlus
        Next

        With item(0)
            .Content = New String("Lundi")
            .Value = DayOfWeek.Monday
        End With
        With item(1)
            .Content = New String("Mardi")
            .Value = DayOfWeek.Tuesday
        End With
        With item(2)
            .Content = New String("Mercredi")
            .Value = DayOfWeek.Wednesday
        End With
        With item(3)
            .Content = New String("Jeudi")
            .Value = DayOfWeek.Thursday
        End With
        With item(4)
            .Content = New String("Vendredi")
            .Value = DayOfWeek.Friday
        End With
        With item(5)
            .Content = New String("Samedi")
            .Value = DayOfWeek.Saturday
        End With
        With item(6)
            .Content = New String("Dimanche")
            .Value = DayOfWeek.Sunday
        End With

        For Each it As ComboBoxItemPlus In item
            CBB_Jour.Items.Add(it)
        Next
```

And it returns me the following error :

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=L'index était hors limites. Il ne doit pas être négatif et doit être inférieur à la taille de la collection.
Nom du paramètre : index
  Source=mscorlib
  Arborescence des appels de procédure :
   à System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   à System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   à AutoFHT.DocumentFHTEditor.FillCBB_Jour() dans C:\Users\BOUCKB\Source\Repos\AutoFHT\AutoFHT\DocumentFHTEditor.xaml.vb :ligne 35
   à AutoFHT.DocumentFHTEditor.DocumentFHTEditon_Initialized(Object sender, EventArgs e) dans C:\Users\BOUCKB\Source\Repos\AutoFHT\AutoFHT\DocumentFHTEditor.xaml.vb :ligne 21
   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.RaiseInitialized(EventPrivateKey key, EventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFireInitialized()
   à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EndInit()
   à MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.InitializationGuard(XamlType xamlType, Object obj, Boolean begin)
```

telling me that item(0) is not instanciated.

I've try to instanciate them out of the `For Each` statement, and it works fine. But, again, I'll have to do this with lists I don't know the length, and that's why I want to do it like this.

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the source of my problem.

the `For Each` statement refers to instanciated objects. In order to make it work, i Used a classic `For`.